# Chrome extension added but not in extensions list

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I created and uploaded a Gmail extension to the Chrome Store and have been trying to test it. I deleted it from my extensions list in Chrome and when I went to go re-download it from the Web Store it said "Added to Chrome" and would not let me re-download it. I found a few solutions that described how to delete cached data on a PC, but I'm using a Mac. Any ideas?

I'm a total newbie at this so any help would be appreciated. Also not a very strong Mac user. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your Chrome browser, if the extension still not exist, [reset the chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214) settings to default, you need to do this if apps or extensions you installed changed your settings without your knowledge. Your saved bookmarks and passwords won't be cleared or changed.

- Open Chrome.
- In the top right, click the icon menu
- Click Settings.
- At the bottom, click Show advanced settings.
- Under the section "*Reset settings*,” click Reset settings.
- In the box that appears, click *Reset*. ​